# How to make an array with all the enum values in system verilog?

Tags: system-verilog

I have an enum :

```
typedef enum { enum_A = 1, enum_B = -5, enum_C = 10 } enum_t;
```

I want to make an array that has all the values of the enum:

```
enum_t enum_array[ enum_t.num() ] = { enum_A, enum_B, enum_C };
```

The problem is how to initialize the array without litrally writing the enum values?

I tried foreach & simple for - nothing works...

```
enum_t enum_array[ enum_t.num() ] =   enum_array_alues();
function   enum_t [enum_t.num() -1:0] enum_array_alues();
    automatic enum_t enum_val = enum_t.first();
    foreach ( enum_array_alues[val] ) begin
        enum_array_alues[val] = enum_val;
        enum_val              = enum_val.next(); << .next() on a non-contiguous enum type not supported
    end
endfunction;
```

Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

System Verilog could be ugly :-). This is one of these cases. You cannot use enum methods on typedefs, you need an enum variable to do so. Also, function return type cannot be directly defined as an array, you need a typedef for it.

Also, different compilers have their own minds as well. The following works with vcs, mentor and aldera. However, it **failed** with *cadence*.

```
  typedef enum { enum_A = 1, enum_B = -5, enum_C = 10, hello } enum_t;
  enum_t enum_var;
  typedef enum_t enum_a[enum_var.num()];
  
  enum_a enum_array;

  initial begin
    enum_array = enum_array_values();
  end
  
  function  automatic enum_a enum_array_values();
    enum_t enum_val = enum_val.first;  
    
    foreach(enum_array_values[i]) begin
      enum_array_values[i]  = enum_val;
      enum_val = enum_val.next();
    end
  endfunction
```

So, my suggestion is to use `dynamic arrays`. It seems that this method below works with all compilers in eda playground. It is less ugly but requires a bit more code.

```
module top;
// Code your design here
 typedef enum { enum_A = 1, enum_B = -5, enum_C = 10 } enum_t;
 typedef enum_t enum_array_t[];
  
  enum_t enum_array[];

  initial begin
    enum_array =   enum_array_values();
    foreach (enum_array[i])
      $display(enum_array[i].name);
  end
  
  function  automatic enum_array_t enum_array_values();
    int i = 0;
    enum_t enum_val;
    enum_val = enum_val.first();
    
    forever begin
      enum_array_values     = new [i+1] (enum_array_values);
      enum_array_values[i]  = enum_val;
      if (enum_val == enum_val.last)
        break;
      i++;
      enum_val = enum_val.next();
    end
  endfunction
endmodule
```

Comment: :-( The .next() of enum_val = enum_val.next(); does not work on unordered enum :-(

enum_val              = enum_val.next(); << .next() on a non-contiguous enum type not supported

Comment: Not sure what you mean. It works. and it is supposed to work according to lrm.

Answer (score 0):

A `do-while` loop works well for iterating over enums

```
module top;
  typedef enum { enum_A = 1, enum_B = -5, enum_C = 10 } enum_t;
  typedef enum_t enum_list_t[$];
  
  enum_list_t enum_array = enum_array_values();
    
  function automatic enum_list_t enum_array_values;
    enum_t tmp = tmp.first;
    do begin
      enum_array_values.push_back(tmp);
      tmp = tmp.next;
    end
    while (tmp  != tmp.first);
  endfunction
  
  initial $display("%p", enum_array);
endmodule
```

Comment: next operator does not work with "not ordered enum" :-(
"enum_val              = enum_val.next(); << .next() on a non-contiguous enum type not supported"

Comment: There is no such restriction in the IEEE 1800-2017 LRM and all SystemVerilog simulators on EDAPlayground support this. There is absolutely no way to do this programmatically without the next() method.